# Is there a way to better understand the results of a Sphinx query?

Tags: sphinx

I have simple Sphinx query that returns some irrelevant results. Is there any way in Sphinx to get more details for a specific query results, i.e. why each item matched and how the weight was built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere is PACKEDWEIGHTS() function that might be interesting

In sphinxQL there is also SHOW PLAN, which can be insightful if your query is complex.